# How to install the old value of the cell

Tags: jquery

The idea is this: there Is a plate with the values, double-click on the cell start to make it in the INPUT, and how to make cell value to appear in the "input".
[Code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcgrB/)

Here is my function which makes converting and should display the value of the cell in the "input":

```
function convertToInput() {
    $('td.editable').on('dblclick', function(){
        $(this).html(function() {
            var input = '<input type="text" name="fname" />';
            var textEditable = $('td.editable');
            return input + textEditable;
        });
    });
    $('td.editable').keypress(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 13 ) {
            $(this).html('<td class="editable"></td>');
        }
    });
}
```

here's a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some markup as well, and preferably a JSFiddle.

Comment: ok, now I'll try to make

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dcgrB/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to get a reference of the cell contents before showing the input and a reference of the input's value before removing it

```
$('td.editable').on('dblclick', function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(function() {
        var input = '<input type="text" name="fname" value="'+value+'" />';
        return input;
    });
});
$('td.editable').keypress(function(event) {
    var value = $(this).find('input').val();
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        $(this).html(value);
    }
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SV9Sg/1/)**

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: But how do the comit input, for example by pressing the ENTER button and then pressing the left mouse button outside a table?

Comment: @Artem I'm sorry I didn't understand your question, you want to close the input when the user clicks outside the cell?

Comment: @Artem and you want to go back to the original cell value or keep the input's value?

Comment: keep the input's value

Comment: because in the future this new value is transmitted with AJAX in the database

Comment: @Artem Check this update http://jsfiddle.net/SV9Sg/2/ I added a handler for the blur event on the input

Comment: also there are a couple plugins that already provide this type of functionality, I suggest you check this one out http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: Cool! Very cool! Thank you ) Maybe tell me how to realize sending using AJAX this value into the database

Comment: @Artem that's more outside the scope of your question, I suggest you ask another question but before you do I recommend you look at some plugins like the one I mentioned because there's no need to work for creating something that others have already done and probably offer much more functionality

Comment: I understand you, thanks for the help, very grateful to you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wBq5M/

First, you have to set the contents of the `<td>` to *only* be the `<input>` on double click.

```
$('td.editable').on('dblclick', function(){
    var myText = $(this).text();
    var input = $('<input type="text" name="fname" />').val(myText);
    $(this).html(input);
});
```

Then, you need to lift in the value of the text input on keypress:

```
$('td.editable').keypress(function(event) {
    var textValue = $('input', this).val();    // Gets the text in <input>
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        $(this).html('<td class="editable">' + textValue + '</td>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('td.editable').on('dblclick', function(){
var current_td= $(this);
var txt= current_td.html();
        current_td.html(function() {
            var input = $("<input type='text' name='fname' />").val(txt);
            return input ;
        });
    });

$('td.editable').keypress(function(event) {
    var value = $(this).find('input').val();
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        $(this).html('<td class="editable">'+value+'</td>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Very good! It might be worth saving the original text into some data field for comparison or in case the user hits an 'undo' button, like `current_td.data('origtxt',txt)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td.editable').on({
   'dblclick': function(){
      var txt=this.innerHTML;
      $(this).data('orig',txt); 
             .html($('<input type="text" name="fname" />').val(txt));
      },
   'keypress': function(event) {
      switch ( event.keyCode ) {
       case 13 :  $(this).html($('input',this).val()) ; break; // return
       case 27 :  $(this).html($(this).data('orig'))  ; break; // escape
      }
})
```

In the `data` property of each td you will find the original txt for restoring if necessary ...

Comment: Oooo nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('td.editable').on('dblclick', function(){
    var $this = $(this), text = $.trim($this.text());

    $('<input />', {
        name: 'fname',
        value: text
    }).appendTo($this.empty())
});

$('td.editable').on('keypress', 'input', function(event){
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        var $this = $(this), text = $.trim($this.val());
        $(this).closest('td').html(text);
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gHX29/)